# How to use accordions in angular?

Tags: angularjs

I have an accordion like the following. The issue I am having is if I click on "Section One", the accordion appears to expand, but in fact it refreshes the page and I cant collapse it. How to allow the accordion to open, but not cause a page refresh? (I would like the accordion to be able to open multiple sections at the same time)

```
        <div class="accordion">
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle-small" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordianParent" href="#sectionOne" style="border-left: 3px solid red;padding-left:10px;">
                        Section One
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionOne" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner-small">
                        Here is all the wonderful stuff in section ONE.<br>
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accordion-group">
                <div class="accordion-heading">
                    <a class="accordion-toggle-small" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordianParent" href="#sectionTwo">
                        Section Two
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionTwo" class="accordion-body collapse">
                    <div class="accordion-inner-small">
                        Here is all the wonderful stuff in section TWO.<br>
                        <br>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the Bootstrap accordion and the `href` link that is in the accordion is not being intercepted by Angular and hence the full page load.

I suggest you look at [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) or [Angularstrap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/) for accordion. Or else look at bootstrap docs to find if the behaviour can be supported without href.

Comment: My project already uses bootstrap (not any special angular version of bootstrap), not UI Bootstrap or Angularstrap. Is there some simple way to use it without going UI Bootstrap or Angularstrap? Or is it required?

Comment: Can you try a without href or use a different html element like div\button for it.

Comment: See the code for the above components, it may give you some idea.

Comment: I have grunt, not sure if grabbing any of those would overwrite everything I have now that is non-UI Bootstrap or Angularstrap. The fiddle you have allows only one at a time to open. Not sure if the components have the flexibility to allow multiple open at the same time. It would be helpful if your fiddle could do that.